# C# / EF Core / SQL Server: I am doing commits to two separate databases (on two servers) within ONE transaction. Why is this working correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I need to do CRUD operations on two separate databases (on two separate on-premise servers) within ONE transaction. All database changes should be rolled back completely if any stored procedure or CRUD operation in the transaction fails. I was told to use `TransactionScope`, and that distributed transactions are not supported (which is true; I got an error *"distributed transactions are not supported on this platform"* when I tried using `TransactionScope`).

However, I just tried nested regular transactions as shown in the code below, and it did everything I wanted. Curious to know:

- Why does this work correctly? What am I not understanding?
- Is the code correct for my purposes? Should I be wary of any edge cases?

```
// DbContexts for my 2 DBs dependency-injected
MyFirstDB _my1st_DbContext;
MySecondDB _my2nd_DbContext;
...
MyFirstDB _my1st_DbContext;
MySecondDB _my2nd_DbContext;
...
public async Task ExecuteOperations()
{
    var secondTransac = _my2nd_DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()

    using (var firstTransac = _my1st_DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
    {
        try
        {
            await _my1st_DB_StoredProcService.GenerateStudentRecord();
 
            await _my1st_DbContext.AnimalTable.AddAsync(new Animal{Name="McDogFace"});
            await _my1st_DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            using (secondTransac)
            {
                await _my2nd_DbContext.VehicleTable.AddAsync(new Vehicle { Brand = "BMW" });
                await _my2nd_DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                // This stored procedure throws an error to roll back
                // all the DB operations done so far on both DBs
                // Note: This is a call to a my1st_DB stored proc
                await _my1st_DB_StoredProcService.GenerateEmployeeRecord();

                await secondTransac.CommitAsync();
            }
      
            await firstTransac.CommitAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            await firstTransac.RollbackAsync();
            await secondTransac.RollbackAsync();
            throw ex.InnerException ?? new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What Happens when Firsttransaction.commit() throws? You could throw an exception one Line above to Test it. I am Not Sure 2nd Transaction can Rollback then.

Comment: Ah, the second transaction commit gets completed in this case. I guess I need to move the first transaction commit into the second transaction's scope. If I make this change, does the order/sequence of transaction commits matter?

Comment: You could use a `TransactionScope` if you want both to commit or rollback together. That would use MSDTC to make sure everything is coordinated.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this work correctly? What am I not understanding?

You need to define "correctly" here. But this are different transactions from different `DbContext`'s which do not know anything about each other, so there is no reason for them not to work.

> Is the code correct for my purposes? Should I be wary of any edge cases?

No. Try throwing an exception right before the `await firstTransac.CommitAsync();` and check the results:

```cs
try
{
    // ...

    using (var secondTransac = _my2nd_DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // ...
    }
      
    throw new Exception();
    await firstTransac.CommitAsync();
}
```

Comment: Ah, the second transaction commit gets completed in this case. I guess I need to move the first transaction commit into the second transaction's scope. If I make this change, does the order/sequence of transaction commits matter?

Comment: @wally2 it will not help. You will have the same issue but "reversed". Think of `throw new Exception()` here as any potential "unexpected" situation - like server crashing, app stopping, etc.

Comment: @wally2 this is quite common problem (for example in microservice architecture), usually it is solved either via eventual consistency approach (google the Saga pattern), two-phase commit protocol or other solutions for distributed transactions.